# Fetch a commit by sha1 ID

Tags: git

Is there a concise way to fetch a particular *commit* (by sha1) from a remote repository (as opposed to fetching a particular *branch*)?  My first thought was

```
git fetch <remote-url> <sha1>
```

but that doesn't work.  It is possible to use `git ls-remote` to see if the commit you're looking for happens to correspond to some remote ref and pull that.  But that can fail if the commit you want is buried in the history of one of those refs, plus it seems like there must be a more concise way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Quoting a [thread from the Git mailing list archive](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/115811):

> No, out of security concerns;  imagine you included some proprietary 
>   source code by mistake, and undo the damage by forcing a push with a 
>   branch that does not have the incriminating code.  Usually you do not 
>   control the garbage-collection on the server, yet you still do not want 
>   other people to fetch "by SHA-1".